# SSL error when installing django for python3

Tags: django, python-3.x, ssl, pip

```
$ pip3 install django

Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after 

connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(185090184, '[X509] no certificate or crl found (_ssl.c:3732)'),)': /simple/django/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(185090184, '[X509] no certificate or crl found (_ssl.c:3732)'),)': /simple/django/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(185090184, '[X509] no certificate or crl found (_ssl.c:3732)'),)': /simple/django/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(185090184, '[X509] no certificate or crl found (_ssl.c:3732)'),)': /simple/django/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(185090184, '[X509] no certificate or crl found (_ssl.c:3732)'),)': /simple/django/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for django
```

I have tried various solutions. I installed python3.7 and then tried but same.
I also tried this but the result was also same.

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools ca-certificates
```

and same thing happens when I install django in a venv. Same goes for the installing a specific version of django.

Comment: Check your internet connection.

Comment: internet connection is fine.

Comment: Can you try to run "ping pypi.org" in the prompt.

Comment: pinging pypi.org is also working fine.

Comment: found the solution [here](https://python-forum.io/Thread-Cannot-update-or-install-anything-with-pip-SSL-error)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu, yet, i solved this just running updates, then fixing dpkg configure -a, it seems installed all the certificates, then upgrade.